# Secure logging in to a Vue.js SPA

Tags: javascript, vue.js, security, routes, vuejs-routing

I'm pretty new to Vue.js, I followed lots of tutorials, but one thing bothers me.
Let's say I'm building a SPA. The user can log in and then access data using a RESTful API.

So the first step would be to send my login information (username, password) to the API and receive a token. The token would be saved to my vuex and also to the localstorage/cookie so the user stays logged in after a page refresh.

All of the other requests to the API would be signed by the token.

My routes are set up:

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/dashboard', name: 'dashboard', component: Dashboard, meta: { requiresAuth: true }
    },
    {
        path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: Login,
    },
]
```

I'm using a route guard to protect the /dashboard page from displaying to a non-logged in user:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if (!store.getters.loggedIn) {
            next({ path: "/login" })
        } else {
            next();
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
})
```

My concern is with the **loggedIn** getter from vuex store which is implemented this way:

```
const getters = {
    loggedIn(state) {
         return state.token !== null;
    }
};
```

Everything is working as it supposed to. I understand that without a access token I won't be able to get data from a server.

**But...**

I can open the developer tools, put an access_token to my localstorage with a random value, refresh the page and suddenly I can access the /dashboard page.

So my question is, how to avoid this scenario?

My first idea was, to have 2 pages - the login page and the second one which contains the SPA. The authentication would be done via session server-side and the SPA page could be accessed only to a logged in user.

Or is there some standard way to to this, so my SPA can handle this?

Comment: well i would do a "checkIsLoggedIn" api function. which triggers on every route change. if the response of the api is a 401, ur user should leaded to the login page on any attempt to reach a other site

Comment: You can't "really" "secure" the front-end and also, you could always workaround it if you want to, you have to secure your backend with every call, so either a check with JWT or cookie, you have to check ion every call if the token or cookie is still valid. If not you could throw an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as said in the comments, i would create a `checkLogin()` like this:

```js
checkLogin() {
      axios
        .get('/webapi/check')
        .then(() => {})
        .catch(err => {
          if (err.response.status === 401) {
            // use a mutation to toggle your "loggedIn" state
            this.$store.commit('loggedIn', false)
            if (this.$route.path !== '/login') {
              this.$router.push('/login')
            }
          }
        })
    }
```

and there for u can use ur routeGuard to use the function on each change

and ofc ur backend should't allow valid backend responses without the token

---

**UPDATED**

u need a state for loggedIn
then u do a mutation to toggle this state depending on how your backend response.

Comment: That was my second guess - to get the current user on each route change. I haven't found a single tutorial which does this. It seems to me as a good idea.